# Replicator+ Motherboard Model

Tags: makerbot, replicator+

What is the make/model of a [MakerBot Replicator+](https://www.makerbot.com/3d-printers/replicator/) motherboard?

I'm assuming that the make is now MakerBot since they are now closed-source.

Comment: really good question. someone who has it should open his machine...

Comment: I don't have a MakerBot Replicator+ to verify with but, if this [Geetech wiki post](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Mighty_Board) is to be believed, MakerBot printers use their own own open source design called 'MightyBoard'.

Comment: @Dr.MantisTobbogan Thanks for the link, but that's for the original Replicator generation that was released around 2011. Since then MakerBot Industries has gone closed-source. The Replicator+ has its controls screwed shut and I'm afraid if I open it there might be some alignment issues, given the history of their frame designs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be this board, [MakerBot 5th Generation motherboard](https://www.shropshire3dprinters.co.uk/makerbot-5th-generation-motherboard.html), ([original image](https://www.shropshire3dprinters.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/a/makerbot-ersatzteil-motherboard-replicator-5.png))

[image: MakerBot 5th Generation motherboard]

The image was very small, so it is rather blurry, I'm afraid.

I have contacted the suppliers for confirmation, and will update this answer, when/if I get a reply.

However, according to this eBay item, [Makerbot Replicator Motherboard Carriage](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Makerbot-Replicator-Motherboard-Carriage-/322836559222), it *could* be inferred<sup>1</sup> that the same motherboard (**MP6292**) is used in the Fifth Generation *and* the Replicator+

> This part is the aluminum carriage that attaches the main board to the
>   printer frame.
>
> Compatible with Makerbot Replicator Fifth Generation (5th Gen) and
>   Replicator+ (Plus).
>
> NOTE: Motherboard show here is for illustration purposes only!
>   Motherboard (MP6292) is NOT included.
>
> Main board presses right onto the carriage. No special tools are
>   needed for assembly. Retaining screw is included.

[image: Makerbot Replicator Motherboard Carriage]

A much clearer shot of the MP6292 Motherboard

[image: MP6292 Motherboard]

---

<sup>1</sup> However, that depends on whether you want to trust eBay descriptions.